# IceFaces: panelPopup autoCentre problem with IE

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm having some problems with panelPopup and IE8. When I set autoCentre="true" and positionOnLoadOnly="true", I expect the popup to appear in the center of the view port and stay put there. This works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but in IE the popup "follows the scroll", if you see what I mean. I.e if the page where the popup is displayed is longer than the popup the popup is re-centered when I scroll the page. Also, and this is a bigger issue - if the popup is longer than the page I can only scroll part of the way down it, then it's re-centered. This means I can never see the information at the bottom of the popup...

This is the code used to generate the popup:

`<ice:panelPopup

    id="popup"

    positionOnLoadOnly="true"

    autoCentre="true"

    style="z-index:999; background: #FFFFFF;"

    resizable="false"

    draggable="false"

    modal="true"

    clientOnly="true"

    visible="#{SomeBean.popupRendered}" >`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the autoCentre option is supposed to keep it centered through scrolling and window resizing but dragging should disable it.  Turning draggable to true might give you reasonable results because the user can drag it to a position they can see the entire popup.

Comment: Yep, that might be it - we decided to break the dialog down using a panelTabSet instead of just the looong list we had previously. That get's us out of the whole scrolling game.